# Android: Edittext to show Name of associated email like GMAIL

Tags: android, autocomplete, android-edittext

Hi. I have developed a mail app in android and i want to customize `EditText` like Gmail compose screen to address box if type the to address. It's shows only recipient name like below figure

[image]

and for example name is already saved for an email address it must show above figure and if not exist, then only show email address in `EditText` in android.

I don't know how to achieve like this can anyone help me on this and thanks.

Comment: In gmail, the mail id you enter, has a contact name, hence, it displays that contact name in that fancy box. What do you intend to display in that fancy box instead of the contact name?

Comment: i want to show the mail id...